# Shell tweak to show current path in addition

Tags: 10.10, bash, command-line, bashrc

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 and now I got in the shell something like that:

```
machine1user@mylinux:~:
```

how can i change it to

```
machine1user@mylinux:/my/current/path :~: ?
```

Answer (score 6):

the '~' at the end **IS** your current path. :)

Comment: The `~` refers to your home directory. If you run `pwd`, you would see something like `/home/user` (run `echo $HOME` to see the path to your home directory)

Answer (score 2):

Open `~/.bashrc` in your text editor. Search for this:

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

and change it to this:

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:$PWD\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: $PWD\a\]$PS1"
```

Specifically, you're replacing `\w` with `$PWD`. The first reference sets the text for your command prompt; the second sets the title which is usually shown in the menu bar of your terminal.